# Im not understanding why I'm recieving the error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, state

Im trying to load the information from a database to my React App. Everything is working as expected except for the map function I'm running. Im trying to list all the genres of the given movie in the div.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';
import play from '../../img/play-icon.svg';
import './hero-display.scss';

class HeroDisplay extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            movie: {},
            trailer: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://petflix.herokuapp.com/movie')
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({
                    movie: response.data
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    openTrailer = () => {
        this.setState({
            trailer: true
        });
    }

    closeTrailer = () => {
        this.setState({
            trailer: false
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { movie, trailer } = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                <div className="hero-display__container" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${movie.backdropURL})`}}>
                    <div className="hero-display__movie-information">
                        <img className="hero-display__movie-logo" src={movie.logoURL} alt=""/>
                        <h1 className="hero-display__heading">Watch Now</h1>
                        <p className="hero-display__movie-description">{movie.description}</p>
                        <div className="hero-display__control-buttons">
                            <button onClick={this.openTrailer} className="hero-display__button play">
                                <img src={play} alt=""/>
                                Play Trailer
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="hero-display__rating">
                        <p>{movie.rating}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={trailer ? "movie__trailer showing" : "movie__trailer hidden"}>
                    <div className="movie-trailer__container">
                        <button className="movie-trailer__close-button" onClick={this.closeTrailer}></button>
                        <ReactPlayer className="video-player" light={movie.backdropURL} volume={0} loop={true} playing={true} image={movie.backdropURL} muted={false} url={movie.trailerURL}/>
                        <div className="movie__information">
                            <div className="movie-trailer__title-add">
                                <h1 className="movie-trailer__title">{movie.title}</h1>
                                <button className="movie-trailer__button"></button>
                            </div>
                            <p className="movie-trailer__rating">{movie.rating}</p>
                            <p className="movie-trailer__director">Directed By: {movie.director}</p>
                            <p className="movie-trailer__description">{movie.description}</p>
                            {movie.genres.map((genre) => {
                                return (
                                    <p className="movie-trailer__genres">{genre}</p>
                                )
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default HeroDisplay;
```

The map function works in a different functional component when the state is passed as a prop, but not in the class component itself. Id appreciate the help.

An example of a movie object that is stored in state.

```
{
  "title": "101 Dalmatians",
  "description": "A brave young man is thrust into adulthood as he and his courageous team of sled dogs embark on a grueling and treacherous cross-country marathon.",
  "director": "Stephen Herek",
  "genres": [
      "Adventure",
      "Family",
      "Comedy"
  ],
  "rating": "G",
  "backdropURL": "https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/mz75dVXfen4J1Z0R8DbTenXNywz.jpg",
  "posterURL": "https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/8o2ADoAyG796UwTjwBFjPyBz0yG.jpg",
  "trailerURL": "https://www.themoviedb.org/video/play?key=K2CTJS12RdI",
  "logoURL": "https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/noruOCRUoWndPPDPJYdR7kVsiq5.png"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening due to the `generes` property of `movie` state is not available before the api call.

So instead of direct access of property.

```
  {movie.genres.map((genre) => {
       return (
          <p className="movie-trailer__genres">{genre}</p>
      )
   })}
```

use optional chaining with `?.`

```
  {movie?.genres?.map((genre) => {
       return (
          <p className="movie-trailer__genres">{genre}</p>
      )
   })}
```

Answer (score 2):

This part:

```
      {movie.genres.map((genre) => {
           return (
              <p className="movie-trailer__genres">{genre}</p>
          )
       })}
```

Should be

```
      {movie.genres && movie.genres.map((genre) => {
           return (
              <p className="movie-trailer__genres">{genre}</p>
          )
       })}
```

Alternatively, you could do `movie?.genres?.map((genre) => {...`

Otherwise `movie.genres` is undefined on first render.